# how can I place an element of a jPanel over another in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextarea, jlist

I'm using the graphic tool of netbeans and I have a `JPanel` on which I put a `JTextArea`.
Then, I need to create a `JList` on the `JTextArea`, but it is created below.

https://gyazo.com/7f8c3613317b49e72edea34c040115c1

Is there any way to sort the elements of a `JPanel` or how can I do it?

Thank you

Comment: A JList **on** a JTextArea? Why?

Comment: Because I am programming a text predictor, and when I write in the JTextArea, I need that over it, jList appears with the suggestions.

Comment: You probably should use a pop-up menu or other pop-up component, perhaps within a JDialog, for something like this, one triggered by changes in the JTextArea's Document. Regardless, without your [mcve] it will be hard to provide a decent answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic code would be something like:

```
int offset = textArea.getCaretPosition();
Rectangle location = textArea.modelToView(offset);
JList list = new JList(...);
list.setVisibleRowCount(...);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
scrollPane.setSize(scrollPane.getPreferredSize();
scrollPane.setLocation(location.x, location.y);
textArea.add(scrollPane);
```

Once you select  an item from the list you would then need to remove the scrollpane from the text area.